# Not able to use AllRowsReader using Astyanax

Tags: scala, cassandra, astyanax

I wrote the following code in Astyanax AllRowsReader receipt

```
object CassandraScanner extends App with CassandraHelper {
   val context = getContext("movielens_small")
   val cf = new ColumnFamily[UUID, String]("movielens_small", UUIDSerializer.get, StringSerializer.get)
   val keyspace = context.getClient
   var count : AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0)
   val allReader = new AllRowsReader.Builder(keyspace, cf)
      .withPageSize(100)
      .withConcurrencyLevel(10)
      .withPartitioner(null)
      .forEachRow { case row : Row[UUID, String] =>
            val cols = row.getColumns
            val movieName = cols.getColumnByName("name")
            val movieNameVal = movieName.getStringValue
            count.incrementAndGet()
            true
      }
      .build()
      .call()
   println(s"Total value ${count.get()}")
}
```

This code however throws and exception

```
18:12:22,759  INFO ThriftKeyspaceImpl:745 - Detected partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner for keyspace movielens_small
18:12:22,820 ERROR AllRowsReader:524 - Error process token/key range
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=192.168.1.169(192.168.1.169):9160, latency=32(32), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table movielens_small)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:397)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.recipes.reader.AllRowsReader$1.call(AllRowsReader.java:447)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.recipes.reader.AllRowsReader$1.call(AllRowsReader.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table movielens_small)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result$get_range_slices_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:17430)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result$get_range_slices_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:17397)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_range_slices_result.read(Cassandra.java:17323)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. The problem was with the line

```
val cf = new ColumnFamily[UUID, String]("movielens_small", UUIDSerializer.get, StringSerializer.get)
```

here the name of the column family must be the name of the table we are scanning. So in my case it was "movies". (movielens_small is the name of my keyspace ... not column family).

So the working line is

```
val cf = new ColumnFamily[UUID, String]("movies", UUIDSerializer.get, StringSerializer.get)
```

when I made this change, i was able to scan the table easily.